# Add confirmation box for "add to cart" button (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, product-list

Suggest solution to add confirmation box for "**add to cart**" button in **product list view**.

It should display before adding product to cart

I searched for many extensions but not found any.

Answer (score 3):

Using some javascript you can easily add confirmation box on "add to cart" instead of any extension and it will not take much time to load as compare to any extension.